# Added new Printer, now network printers need updating

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-printer, print-server

We recently added a new network printer to our print server. Now windows 7 users are being prompted to update the driver for all network printers which requires admin rights.

Seems like it is a known issue per this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946225.

Point and Print seems like it would be a preventative measure but we do not have a 2008 DC. Also I need to resolve this now, preferable without going around to each individual pc, and updating the driver under my admin account. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login as a domain admin to one of the Windows 7 computers, install RSAT on that computer, Enable the Group Policy Management Console, then use that to create a group policy for the domain with the proper point and print settings.

Comment: That was it. Great solution!